# Making dataframe from numpy - why columns are mixed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have numpy array `k` with the shape (11456, 5).

And I'm creating pandas dataframe from it this way:

```
submission = pd.DataFrame({"ID":id_test, "Adoption":k[:,0], "Died":k[:,1],"Euthanasia":k[:,2],"Return_to_owner":k[:,3],"Transfer":k[:,4]})

submission.head()
```

However ID column is now located in the middle, that looks really strange for me:

```
    Adoption    Died      Euthanasia    ID  Return_to_owner Transfer
0   0.167068    0.005591    0.005023    1   0.813333        0.008985
1   0.610528    0.003572    0.003822    2   0.376651        0.005426
2   0.732384    0.002936    0.003082    3   0.256638        0.004959
```

I found the solution how to fix that:

```
cols = ['ID',"Adoption", "Died", "Euthanasia","Return_to_owner", "Transfer"]

submission = submission[cols]
```

But why does it happen?

Comment: Because you passed a dict as the data param so inherently the order of the keys may not be the same as the order of dict key creation, if you pass the desired order as the `columns` param then you get the df constructed as your desire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add parameter columns to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
cols = ['ID',"Adoption", "Died", "Euthanasia","Return_to_owner", "Transfer"]

pd.DataFrame({"ID":id_test, "Adoption":k[:,0],}, columns=cols)
```

because if parameter `columns` is not set, columns are sorted alfanumeric.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! Nice day!